# Unable to find the pattern in the following text

Tags: python, regex

I have a file which has a pattern as follows;

```
    | |                                
    ###O                               
    | |           | |                  
                  ###O                 
                  | |              | | 
                                   ###O
                                   | |
```

I am trying to find all the above patterns. But I'm also stuck at getting empty lines. Here is my pattern code,

`(?:.+?)(\|\s\|(?:.+\n.+)###O)`

**update**:  After emma's suggestion `.+?(\|\s\|).+?\s+(###O).+?\s+(\|\s\|)`

still not able to find the exact pattern.

Tested in `https://regex101.com/`

Comment: this regex '\|\s{1}\|' will find "| |"

Comment: I don't think what you're asking for is possible using the `re` library alone. You need a function. The reason why is because `| |  [LONG_SPACES]   | |` for the second query appear `on the same line` The `re` library doesn't provide a way to backreference a `distance` it can only backreference patterns. Had those been on different lines you could have backreferenced a specific amount of `spaces` easily

Comment: Try it like this `[ \t]+(\|[ \t]\|[ \t]+\n.*###O[ \t]*\n[ \t]+\|[ \t]\|)` https://regex101.com/r/bVZK2b/1/

Comment: Maybe  https://regex101.com/r/o75969/1 will work

Answer (score 0):

[This RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/xw96Xq/1) might help you to find `###0`:

```
.+\|\s\|.+\s+(###O)
```

[image: RegEx]

Answer (score 0):

Try the below regex, it would give you 3 matches with three groups.

```
\s*(\|\s\|)\s*(###O)\s*(\|\s\|)
```

Test link: https://regex101.com/r/Ulb80p/1/